# KeyError when retrieving entry widget data variable

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am trying to read from a csv file to get data on NCAA Basketball teams but when I try to read a users input to the "Entry" widget python takes the empty field as the variable and reads the csv file for a blank space.

```
hometeam = tk.StringVar()
awayteam = tk.StringVar()

label1 = ttk.Label(Teams, text="Enter the Home Team", font=LARGE_FONT)
label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

entry1 = ttk.Entry(Teams, textvariable=hometeam)
entry1.insert(0, "Home Team")
entry1.pack()

label2 = ttk.Label(Teams, text="Enter the Away Team", font=LARGE_FONT)
label2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

entry2 = ttk.Entry(Teams, textvariable=awayteam)
entry2.insert(0, "Away Team")
entry2.pack()


def _login_btn_clicked():
    hometeam = entry1.get()
    awayteam = entry2.get()
    if all(k in result for k in (hometeam, awayteam)):
        tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome John")
        raise_frame(Final)
    elif awayteam or hometeam not in result:
        tm.showerror("Error", "One or more teams are not NCAA Men's  Basketball teams")
elif awayteam == hometeam:
    tm.showerror("Error", "A team cannot play itself")

button = ttk.Button(Teams, text="Calculate", command=_login_btn_clicked)
button.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='left')

button1 = ttk.Button(Teams, text="back", command=lambda: raise_frame(Start))
button1.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='right')

ppg2 = float(result[awayteam][0])
apg2 = float(result[awayteam][1])
rpg2 = float(result[awayteam][2])
bpg2 = float(result[awayteam][3])
spg2 = float(result[awayteam][4])
win_pct2 = float(result[awayteam][5])
rb_pct2 = float(result[awayteam][6])
ast_pct2 = float(result[awayteam][7])
sos2 = float(result[awayteam][8])
fg_pct2 = float(result[awayteam][9])
games2 = float(result[awayteam][10])

ppg1 = float(result[hometeam][0])
apg1 = float(result[hometeam][1])
rpg1 = float(result[hometeam][2])
bpg1 = float(result[hometeam][3])
spg1 = float(result[hometeam][4])
win_pct1 = float(result[hometeam][5])
rb_pct1 = float(result[hometeam][6])
ast_pct1 = float(result[hometeam][7])
sos1 = float(result[hometeam][8])
fg_pct1 = float(result[hometeam][9])
games1 = float(result[hometeam][10])
```

sample data file:
Villanova, 880, 161, 388, 34, 74, 1, 53.7, 52.6, 6.34, 0.497, 11

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/ekpLWvGf

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Files/Code/Python/SPI/Beta/Testgui/c.py", line 70, in <module>
    ppg2 = float(result[awayteam.get()][0])
KeyError: 'Away Team'
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Are you expecting that key to be valid, or is it using the wrong key?

Comment: you have to put `ppg2 = float(result[awayteam.get()][0])` (and other lines) inside `_login_btn_clicked()`. Now they are executed at start - before you click button.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!, from here how would I call the variables from that function to be used to display the results?